# How to set cell color based on another cell value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In MVC Razor gridPanel, how can i set cell color using another cell value?
In the same cell, i can use renderer option that calls javascript function to set cell colors like below:

```
Html.X().Column().Text("Cell_1").DataIndex("cell_1_value").Renderer("change"),
Html.X().Column().Text("Cell_2").DataIndex("cell_2_value")
```

the javaScript function is:

```
var change = function (value) {
            return Ext.String.format(template, (value > 2) ? "green" : "red", value);
        };
```

Is there any way to set "Cell1" color based on "cell_2_value"?
Note that Cell2 belongs to another column.

Comment: You could add a property to your object that calculates cell color. You are basically iterating over a list of objects and making them rows right?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama yes, i m iterating over a model containing list of objects. the information about color is in the "cell_2_value" so why should i add another property? even with another property how can i use it in my code?

Comment: Are you talking server side? or client side?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama client side

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use JavaScript get the background colour of cell 2 and then fire the following JavaScript function? Remember to substitute cell_1_id for the appropriate id.

```
function change_background(cell_2_colour) {
    document.getElementById("cell_1_id").style.backgroundColor=cell_2_colour;
}
```

I hope that helps,

Simon.

Comment: How to call this function in my code? and how pass parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Script Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cell_1"><h1>Cell 1</h1></div>
        <div id="cell_2" style="background-color:orange;"><h1>Cell 2</h1></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("cell_1").style.backgroundColor=cell_2_colour=document.getElementById("cell_2").style.backgroundColor;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope that this helps ...

Simon.